# Streaming from Flash media servers using the RTMP flowplayer

Tags: drupal, rtmp, flowplayer

hi im using this code for streaming rtmp:

```
<?php
  $url = $node->field_url[0]['value'];
  $config = array(
    'clip' => array(
      'autoPlay' => $autoplay,
      'url' => 'myfile.flv',
      'provider' => 'rtmp',
     ),
    'plugins' => array(
       'rtmp'=>array(
         'netConnectionUrl' => 'rtmp://myserver',
         'url' => 'flowplayer.rtmp.swf'
       )
     ),
  );
  print theme('flowplayer', $config);
?>
```

this code doesn't work and nothing shows ?
please help me

Comment: What version of flowplayer caused your trouble?

Answer (score 0):

This would be solved by using the newer revision of flowplayer rtmp player.